# i used preg_replace to replace . with (dot) but it is empty

Tags: php, preg-replace

I tried to use preg_replace but it does not work.

I wrote the code below, but it returns as empty.

```
$str = 'amin.m is 1.2 ^.j ';
echo $str.'<br>';
echo preg_replace('/(\D|\d)\.(\D|\d)', '\1\(dot\)\2', $str);
```

Comment: Great. Did you have a question? This is a Q&A site after all.

Comment: Your regular expression is invalid, obviously, since there is no terminating delimiter. The call to `preg_replace()` throws an error.

Comment: I tested the code in https://regex101.com and it worked but does not work in my project

Comment: So you claim that call does _not_ throw an error for you? Then you probably have error_reporting disabled (which is fine) but did not think of monitoring your http servers error log file (which is _really_ bad).

Comment: @arkascha how should i change it?

Comment: `/(\D|\d)\.(\D|\d)` => `/(\D|\d)\.(\D|\d)/` ...

Comment: @arkascha it works now, thank youuuuuuuuu

Comment: @DeadVampire You are welcome. And... don't forget the lesson you learned: you _cannot_ program php in a web environment without monitoring your http servers error log file. That would be like flying in a narrow cave with your eyes blindfolded...

Answer (score 0):

A couple notes...

- Your pattern is using a pipe `|` between `\D` and `\d`.  These two characters are exact opposites, so I think what you may be wanting is `\S` which would match any non-white space character.  By removing your pipes, your pattern reduces its step count (improves efficiency).
- You don't need to escape your parentheses in your replacement string -- unless you want to see those slashes in the output.

New Pattern: `/(\S)\.(\S)/`  [Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/f3nKoL/1)

New PHP: ([Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8b327cd50ffbe50af124f5bbac1890837509b14))

```
$str = 'amin.m is 1.2 ^.j ';
echo $str.'<br>';
echo preg_replace('/(\S)\.(\S)/','\1(dot)\2',$str);
```

Output:

```
amin.m is 1.2 ^.j 
amin(dot)m is 1(dot)2 ^(dot)j
```